# Importing C code through ctypes is faster than C

Tags: c, python-3.x, performance, ctypes

I was doing a test to compare the speed difference between Python and C. Writting a program both in C and Python to count to a billion.
I was willing to write the most efficient code possible for python.
When I did my tests, Python came out to be faster than C for some reason.

I was definitely expecting C to be faster but I also wanted to do everything I can with the python code to make it as fast as possible. Here's what I ended up with

```c
// count.c
#include <stdio.h>

// a function in c that takes n. counts till n and returns the result
long int count(long int n) {
    long int number = 0;
    for(long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        number++;
    }
    return number;
}

// main function to run that code...
int main() {
    printf("%ld\n", count(1000000000));
    return 0;
}
```

Next I used the same count function from c and called it in my python code.

```py
# count.py
from ctypes import CDLL

# loading the c count function into python using the so files to optimise speed for python
so_file = "./count.so"

count_func = CDLL(so_file).count

print(count_func(1000_000_000))
```

I was still expecting c to be faster than python.
On the terminal - I did the following

```
 ~/playground  cc -fPIC -shared -o count.so count.c -O
 ~/playground  cc -fPIC count.c -o count -O
 ~/playground  time ./count
1000000000
./count  0.51s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.509 total
 ~/playground  time ./count
1000000000
./count  0.52s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.529 total
 ~/playground  time ./count
1000000000
./count  0.55s user 0.00s system 99% cpu 0.552 total
 ~/playground  time python count.py                   
1000000000
python3 count.py  0.29s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.296 total
 ~/playground  time python count.py
1000000000
python3 count.py  0.29s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.300 total
 ~/playground  time python count.py
1000000000
python3 count.py  0.29s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 0.305 total
```

The python code ran consistently faster than the same C code...
Can anybody please explain me what happened here ?

## Update

Further testing on my end showed this was a `gcc` and system specific problem. I tried using clang and it worked as expected.

For anyone interested:
GCC Version

```
gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
```

Clang Version

```
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1
```

System Specification

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS x86_64
```

Comment: It would be interesting to re-run the tests without the printing to see if that's affecting the results.

Comment: I would expect that with optimization enabled, the C code would be optimized down to the equivalent of `int main() {printf("%ld\n", 1000000000); return 0;}`, since the optimizer can compute at compile-time what the function will do.  In testing (on my Mac, with `gcc -O3 -S temp.c`), that is the behavior I see.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I'm on Windows, but that's exactly what the MSVC compiler did.  The loop is gone when optimized.

Comment: @MarkRansom commenting the print statements made no difference

Comment: @JeremyFriesner  I used the `cc` command to compile to so and out files. The -O flag does nothing foc the `cc` command. Therefore i'm guessing it did not optimise the code. I've included it in the question because I wasn't aware that it does not work with `cc`

Comment: @GrayHat does replacing `-O` with `-O3` change anything?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes it does, thanks. Completely removes the loop time. But still. when unoptimised it does not explain how using ctypes can be faster than C.

Comment: @GrayHat it might be interesting to insert a `printf("Hi\n");` call at the top of `main()`, and observe carefully how long the delay is before that gets printed, in both cases.  If it gets printed immediately, that suggests that your unoptimized-`count()` function is running slower under C than under Python; OTOH if you notice some delay before it gets printed, that suggests something is slow in your C program's pre-`main()` process-startup routine (which your Python program doesnt have to execute, since the Python interpreter-executable has its own (optimized) process-startup routine instead)

Comment: Not reproducible here. Check your frequency governor settings, and try running tests in a different order.

Comment: Also double check that you are running the code you think you are running.